# FormData, append image after axios.get, nodejs v20

Tags: node.js, axios, multipartform-data, form-data

I need to POST to an API, and send 'multipart/form-data' including an image file, that i first need to download from the URL i get from the JSON object.

For the life of me, this code was working yesterday, somehow i messed it up...

I'm getting the error:
`TypeError: Failed to execute 'append' on 'FormData': parameter 2 is not of type 'Blob'`

```js
const formData = new FormData()
  for (let key in payload) {
    if (key === 'image') {
      const fileUrl = payload.image
      const fileName = fileUrl.split('/').at(-1)
      const imageResponse = await axios.get(fileUrl, { responseType: 'stream' })
      console.log('got', fileUrl)
      const blob = imageResponse.data
      formData.append('image', blob, fileName)
    } else {
      formData.append(key, payload[key])
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, it had to be something.

The error happens when i use nodejs's native FormData.
If i use npm's `form-data` and keep the code exactly the same it does work